# Content Not Centering Correctly

Tags: css

So there's this image in my code and with following code it is centered correctly horizontally,

```
img#headerImage{
            width: 600px;
            margin-left:auto !important;
            margin-right:auto !important;
        }
```

but when I add `margin-left:-300px;` the image is resized appropriately but it is slightly offset to the left and no longer exactly centered.

Any ideas?

Also, here's some of the HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="headerContent" id="logoContainer">
    <img src="url" style="max-width:600px;"
         id="headerImage" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image"
         mc:allowdesigner="" mc:allowtext="" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You need to post your HTML as well

Comment: Can you post your entire HTML and CSS?

Comment: Oh boy, `!important`, selector specificity and `<table>` walk into a bar… (a heads up: `<img>` is an inline tag, using `margin` won't help you if you don't change the `display` property or use `text-align: center;` instead).

Comment: text-align: center; was the answer! I hadn't noticed that the parent container was had text-align: left; set!

Answer (score 0):

You could better still use margin:0px auto;

Comment: This doesn't fix it, `img` are inline by default. He could remove the margin's altogether and just use text-align: center, or he can add `display: block` to make the img a block-level element.

Answer (score 0):

add `display: block` to your img css

Answer (score 0):

When you say `margin-left:-300px` you are saying you want the picture moved 300px to the left. With a right margin set to auto it will of course be offset left. If you want to make it center and then move it over just slightly then I recommend reading up on this answer here: [Offset div from center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783902/offset-div-from-center)

Also you will want to add

```
display:block;
```